# I want to save my data into an array and then sort and display to user in php

Tags: php

I want to save my data into an array and then sort it and display to user

Please help me out i am new in php

My code is :

```
$sql = "Select * FROM contact_info WHERE user_id = $userid AND name LIKE 'a%' ORDER BY name ASC";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$a = array ();
$i=0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $a[$i]=$row['name'];

}
sort($a);
for ($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
    echo $a[$i]  . '<br>';}

}
```

error comes after this code:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\\ on line 51...so on...

Comment: you are not incrementing $i anywhere in while loop??

Comment: $a[$i++]=$row['name'];

Comment: you can use array_push()

Comment: @Andrew, if you use that code, wont the while loop start at index 1 instead of 0?

Comment: then `$i = -1;` or use `$i++;` after `$a[$i]=$row['name'];` or just `$a[]=$row['name'];`

Comment: Those are valid workarounds yes, but I wanted to clarify my understanding of how the code would work, ie it increments the value of i then returns it, rather than returning the value of i and then incrementing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $a[$i]=$row['name'];
    $i++; // forgot this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the while you need to increment $i.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @user3146137! It sounds like this answer solved your problem. If that's the case, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left, instead of leaving a comment. Everyone will still know that this is the answer that worked for you, plus you and Goikiu get some reputation!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do it because you have an `ORDER BY` in your SQL ...

Comment: Should probably be a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the below code:

```
$a[$i]=$row['name'];
```

use the below code:

```
$a[]=$row['name'];
```

this will automatically assign the incremented index.